# Python: What if we call thread.start() and leave it without join or close?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

When I create a new thread from threading like this:

```
def hello():
    print ('hello')
t1 = threading.Thread(target=hello)
t1.start()
```

If I creating more and more threads like that, would I be out of memory or threads to use?
Is it ok to leave it like that after call start method?

Comment: `join()` just blocks the thread where you make the call.

Answer (score 15):

Yes, if you create a lot of long-running threads, it is theoretically possible to hit the functional OS max for the python process (about 2-3k threads on 32-bit machines, or around 30k for 64-bit machines).

However, it doesn't really matter if you `join()` the threads or not.  The threads will automatically exit when the `target` function returns.